# Index match match - correct approach?

Tags: excel

I have a data source in the format as the one below. In reality, that would contain few thousand rows.

[image]

I need to use something like INDEX-MATCH-MATCH in order to be able to get the "Status" for each "Content" item for each UserID. 
The final result should look like this. The first two columns are not dynamic. 
The INDEX formula goes to C and D.

[image]

I am using the following sequence to try and write the formula, but I don't seem to understand where the problem is.

=INDEX(Sheet1!A:K, [Vertical Position], [Horizontal Position])

look up the user with ID xxx:

=INDEX(Sheet1!A:K, MATCH(A2, Sheet1!A:K,0), [Horizontal Position])

look up the status for eLearn1.

=INDEX(Sheet1!A:K, MATCH(A2, Sheet1!A:K,0), MATCH("Status", Sheet1!A:K,0))

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Match the column in the row (e.g. row 1:1). `MATCH("Status", Sheet1!$1:$1, 0)` for the *column_num* parameter. {edit] Also match the *row_num* to column A. `MATCH(A2, Sheet1!A:A,0)`. Maybe a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) would be better?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear, but I think you are trying to do a LOOKUP based on the values of two columns. So for a particular value of Column A (UserID) and Column B (Content) you need to return Column H (Status).

This can be done using an array formula to return the row number of the matching line which can be fed into INDEX. Note, that this will only work as long as Columns A&B only have unique pairings.

I have set up some sample data:
[image: Sample Data]
Columns A-C are my source data. Cells G2:H4 are the lookup.
The formula is:

=INDEX($C$1:$C$7, SUM(($A$1:$A$7=$F2)* ($B$1:$B$7=G$1)*ROW($C$1:$C$7)))

This needs to be entered as an array formula by pressing CTRL-ALT-ENTER.
The formula works by matching the value you are searching for in both arrays and multiplying out the results. This should give you a result array consisting of all False with one True indicating the matched row. This is then multiplied against the row number to return the correct row to the INDEX formula.